# Diagnostics about LaTeX installation

Tags: pdftex, installing

I have a machine where I know that `pdflatex` plus some packages are installed. I can compile any given `.tex` file on that machine and view the output, but I cannot inspect the machine directly.

What is the easiest way to produce a PDF that describes the LaTeX installation found on that machine, with all the packages, classes, and fonts, plus their versions? Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
tlmgr info
```

lists all TeXLive packages with a preceeding i, if already installed. Or use

```
tlmgr list --only-installed
```

You can also create a complete list as pdf (run with `lualatex --shell-escape <file>`):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4,pagesize]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luacode,ltablex}
\begin{document}
\section*{Installed packages in \TeX{}Live}
\begin{luacode}
local fh,err = io.popen("tlmgr list --only-installed")
if not fh then
  texio.write(err)
  os.exit(-1)
end
tex.print("\\begingroup\\footnotesize\\noindent")
tex.print("\\begin{tabularx}{\\linewidth}{@{} r @{.~} l X @{}}")
local i=0
for line in fh:lines() do
  i = i + 1
  tex.print(i .. "&" .. line:gsub("^i ", ""):gsub(": ", "&", 1)
    :gsub("\\", "\\textbackslash{}"):gsub("_", "\\_"):gsub("$","\\\\"))
end
tex.print("\\end{tabularx}\\endgroup")
fh:close()
\end{luacode}
\end{document}
```

I have no idea how it can be done for MiKteX.

Answer (score 2):

A `pdflatex` version; run with `-shell-escape`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\listpackages}{}
 {
  \krlmlr_list_packages:
 }

\ior_new:N \g_krlmlr_read_stream

\cs_new_protected:Nn \krlmlr_list_packages:
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g_krlmlr_read_stream { |"tlmgr~list~--only-installed" }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_krlmlr_read_stream
   {
    \__krlmlr_process_line:n { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__krlmlr_process_line:n
 {
  \__krlmlr_process_line_aux:w #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__krlmlr_process_line_aux:w #1~#2~#3 \q_stop
 {
  \noindent\texttt{\tl_to_str:n { #2 }}~\tl_to_str:n {#3}\par
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\listpackages

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Just the first few entries and not the whole 76 pages.)

Comment: Nice! Is it possible to align the columns?

Comment: @Sigur Yes, of course, by using `longtable`, for instance. An easy exercise.

Comment: I only recognise the line `\noindent\texttt{\tl_to_str:n { #2 }}~\tl_to_str:n {#3}\par` with TeX commands. So I suppose that here is the place to edit. Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur ``\tl_put_right:Nn \l__krlmlr_table_body_tl { \texttt{\tl_to_str:n { #2 }} & \tl_to_str:n {#3} \\ } }`` and supplement the first macro with `\begin{longtable}{ll} \l__krlmlr_table_body_tl \end{longtable}` Reducing the font size is obviously necessary.